# PHP + Format array to be then used inside query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, format

Let´s say i perform a query like this:

```
$charsnamequery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'bookstable' WHERE 'bookcharactersname' = 'JHON'")
```

This will give back a resource that i then put in an array and use to print the results like this:

```
while ( $fullist = mysql_fetch_array( $charsnamequery ))
{ Print "book title: ".$fullist['id_book'] . ", book author:".$fullist['book_author'] . "
.....etc etc etc";
 }
```

So, lets say that now i want to do is: 
Search on my database for customers who have showed interest in any of those id_book in the past and gather their emails.

I know i am suposed to reformat the array in **someway** so that i can do a new query like:

```
$newquery = mysql_query("SELECT 'email' FROM 'customerstable' WHERE 'id_book_interested_in' IN ($value1,$value2,$value3....etc etc etc)"
```

Hope you can give me a hand with this! Thanks you in advance!

PS: I rather not join the querys even if it were possible for im trying to learn step by step.-

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! I did not know that! I guess i have been reading old tutorials =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the query is not working is because you are wrapping the table name as well as column name with single quote.

```
SELECT * FROM bookstable WHERE bookcharactersname = 'JHON'
```

These are identifiers and not string literals. In this case, backticks are optional since non of them are reserved keywords.

- [MySQL - when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess i just wrote it down badly while posting the question. My actual issue it with getting the "SOMEWAY" (highlighted on the text) done. That is the step i do not know how to perfom